# Подскажите урок по анимации svg рисунка

Tags: jquery, svg, css

Есть круг, его надо анимировать, например, стрелка на 12, она начала крутиться, т.е. 12,1,2,3,4 и так до 12, и тем временем закрашивается этот круг. Подскажите уроки по подобной анимации

Comment: Не могу удержаться, так люблю D3js : ) Вот [красивые примеры](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), всё — svg.

В частности, [часы](http://www.infocaptor.com/dashboard/d3-javascript-visualization-to-build-world-analog-clocks) и [заполнение кругов](https://live.zoomdata.com/zoomdata/visualization?__target=embedded&key=52265abb6abdbcaa8c217789#51db7ad4e4b04caf9ab346db-51db7ad4e4b04caf9ab346d5).

Answer (score 1):

Анимацию SVG можно получить 2 способами: используя SMIL или JavaScript. По поводу доступа к атрибутам из javascript с использованием jQuery с примерами можете посмотреть http://svgmnemo.ru/pub/svgdyn.html и http://svgmnemo.ru/pub/svgdyn_p2.html

Comment: Только ли двумя? Вот [третий](http://letmespellitoutforyou.com/samples/svg/anim_swipeBlur.svg).

Comment: А этот [третий][1] - не относится к SMIL? Впрочем, спасибо, такого применения фильтров я не знал.


  [1]: http://letmespellitoutforyou.com/samples/svg/anim_swipeBlur.svg

Comment: Вы правы, тег `<animate>` это как раз SMIL. Но [третий способ](http://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/) таки есть: CSS! : )